# Select data and display on same page without loading (php/ajax)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am getting user data by passing the id in url and using the select statement where it matches the id in url and display result

But I want this by using ajax. Please help me

```
<div id="show_data">
    <?php
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $category=$_GET['category'];

        if ($category==Hosted) {
            $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM wp_user_host WHERE user_id=$id");
            foreach ( $result as $print ){
    ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td>Name: <?php echo $print->drive_name;?</td>
                <td>Date: <?php echo $print->drive_date;?</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>

</div>

<a href="page.php?id=2&category=Hosted:>VIEW DATA</a>
```

Comment: if want ajax call please visit [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)

Comment: If you can help me with my code rather than giving some link then it will be good.

Comment: Pls. add some info about what you've tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't know how to do this using ajax. I was trying this code


`script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $('.view_data').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'approval_request.php'+id,
            data:id:,   
            success:function(respnose){
               $('#show_data').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});​
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

lets say i have an index file like follow

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <button id="testDom">click to load dom</button>
    <p id="domOutput"></p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("testDom").addEventListener('click', function(){
            loadAjax();
        });

        function loadAjax(){
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var requestUrl = 'test.php';
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if( this.readyState == 4  && ( this.status > 200 || this.status < 300 ) ){
                    console.log("ok");
                    document.getElementById("domOutput").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open('GET', requestUrl);
            xmlHttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

lets say if u click the button ajax call made to the php file called `test.php`

```
<?php 
echo "php file loaded";
```

ouput will printed in the index.html on `p` tag.